# lingui + webpack Cannot find module './*/messages.js' in production

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, web-worker, workbox, linguijs

I have a create-react-app PWA with dynamic loading lingui as in [here](https://lingui.js.org/guides/dynamic-loading-catalogs)
it works correctly locally in `develop` as well as in `production` mode

But, when deployed in production server, something brakes:
*all lingui files are available from server,
*service-worker correctly precaches resources, including all `messages.po` and all `i18n-*` js chunks
*it seems that lazy-importing them in the app doesn't trigger any fetch (not service-worker or xhr either) and fails with an e.g. `Cannot find module './en_GB/messages.js'`

any hint on what to check?

EDIT:
Figured out that webpack correctly maps *.po files to lazy-import-able chuncks urls
but it doesn't create mappings for compiled *.js (or *.json) chuncks ( oddly except for 1 language out of many )
made a temporary workaround
I let app lazy-import i18n uncompiled `.po` files instead of compiled `.js` in production
only side-effect is that *.po files get compiled on runtime by the app, leading to a (tiny unnoticeable) delay time between lang loading and lang appliance

Comment: your [baseUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) set correctly?

Comment: yes @RazRonen, and I found some further interesting info about this issue, you can read it in edited question